# How would Objective-C's automatic reference counting be implemented by a compiler?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management

I've been searching around and I can't figure out how they implemented it? What would the compiler have to do to tell when an object should be freed? I'm not looking for a super detailed response - it would be nice though - but even just a basic run down on the steps the compiler takes to figure out when to free memory would be great.

Comment: The compiler cannot do the complete implementation.  However, it can embed hidden code and otherwise facilitate automatic reference counting.

Comment: @matt The use of `->` throughout that chapter is... odd.  That pattern is used very very rarely in practice.

Comment: @matt It isn't the recommended practice and it is uncommon. Not wrong, but uncommon. Teaching students to use that pattern without the caveat that it isn't standard practice will lead to confusion (personally?  I prefer the pattern even though it is kinda ugly). I say this with 25 years of experience using, teaching, and defining Objective-C

Comment: @matt bbum is being too polite. Since you are now teaching Swift; asking bbum if he knows about Objective-C is like asking chris-lattner if he knows about Swift.

Comment: @matt  As one who came to this late in the game, I always found the - indicating an instance method to signify what you think -> makes explicit.  That is, if you include the prototype, it's clear what's an ivar.  But you're right, it makes it clear they're ivars and not static or global, more so than underscores.

Answer (score 0):

ARC works by analyzing your code to figure how what the ideal lifetime of each object should be, then inserts the necessary retain and release calls automatically. The algorithm requires complete control over the object-ownership in your entire program, which means you’re not allowed to manually call retain, release, or autorelease.

The only memory-related methods you should ever find in an ARC program are alloc and copy. You can think of these as plain old constructors and ignore the whole object-ownership thing.

Please refer to this link - 
http://rypress.com/tutorials/objective-c/memory-management

Comment: That is not correct, because you can mix-up MRR and ARC. The compiler only needed control of a single reference. That is much easier to apply.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler never tells an object that it has to be freed. The compiler tells the object (to be more precise: the runtime environment) that an object is not owned any more by a reference. The runtime environment frees the object. This is done, when no ownership of an object exists anymore (reference counting).

Basically the compiler indicates a ownership, if he generates code that stores a reference to a strong reference variable. (It is not only a reference variable, but a C object. Don't care here about that.) It relinquishes an ownership, when the reference is not stored anymore in the strong reference variable. There are two cases for it:

- A new reference is stored in the strong reference variable.
- The reference variable loses its extent. (It dies itself. But since reference variables are C objects, no reference counting is needed for this. C does not know reference counting.)

This is the basic mechanism. There are more complex scenarios as return values in expressions with other operands having side-effects, but it is the basic mechanism. (For example the subject of reference counting is not the reference variable, but the reference itself, which might be different, if a reference is not stored in a reference variable evaluating a complex expression. But this is not important for the basic understanding.)